# PDI SDK: Reusing SQL connection in input step

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I need to dynamically generate a transformation using the PDI SDK in Java code. The transformation input is an SQL select and the output a text file.

The code below connects correctly to the database for the input step (TableInputMeta):

```
String dbXML =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
          "<connection>" +
              "<name>source</name>" +
              "<server>localhost</server>" +
              "<type>MYSQL</type>" +
              "<access>Native</access>" +
              "<database>db</database>" +
              "<port>3306</port>" +
              "<username>user</username>" +
              "<password>pwdk</password>" +
            "</connection>";

DatabaseMeta dbm = new DatabaseMeta(dbXML);
TableInputMeta in = new TableInputMeta();
in.setDatabaseMeta(dbm);
```

However I would prefer NOT to store the user and password. Moreover, I'm running this code in an application server that already has a pool of DB connections. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// get connection from JNDI
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) initCtx.lookup(jndiName);
java.sql.Connection conn = ds.getConnection();


// reuse connection
DatabaseMeta dbm = new DatabaseMeta();
dbm.setConnection(conn);  // this has not been implemented
```

where `setConnection(conn)` would link the existing connection with the DatabaseMeta object. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I created a JNDI connection in Spoon, this is the XML, but I cannot figure out how to tweak it to make it work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <connection>
    <name>JNDI_CONNECT</name>
    <server/>
    <type>MYSQL</type>
    <access>JNDI</access>
    <database>JNDI_NAME</database>
    <port>1521</port>
    <username/>
    <password>Encrypted </password>
    <servername/>
    <data_tablespace>TAB_DATA</data_tablespace>
    <index_tablespace>TAB_IND</index_tablespace>
    <attributes>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_LOWERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>FORCE_IDENTIFIERS_TO_UPPERCASE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>IS_CLUSTERED</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>PORT_NUMBER</code><attribute>1521</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>QUOTE_ALL_FIELDS</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>STREAM_RESULTS</code><attribute>Y</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>SUPPORTS_BOOLEAN_DATA_TYPE</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
      <attribute><code>USE_POOLING</code><attribute>N</attribute></attribute>
   </attributes>
</connection>
```

This is how I connect to JNDI in Java:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
Connection cn = ds.getConnection();
```

Any insights/working example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your example XML above has the access type set to "Native", which will use the specified parameters. If you'd like to use JNDI, you should set the access type to JNDI. To get a working snippet of XML, try creating the same connection in Spoon for some sample transformation, save the transformation to disk, then inspect the .ktr file looking for the connection with that name. You should find a usable XML snippet that will have the DatabaseMeta use JNDI instead of the provided parameters.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I added an update, it seems that the XML has properties not related to JNDI, such as database type and port number.